# Como saber qual é o nome da classe de um objeto javascript?

Tags: javascript

No PHP podemos descobrir de qual instância um objeto é proveniente através da função `get_class`.

Assim:

```
$ao = new ArrayObject;

get_class($ao); // ArrayObject
```

E no javascript? Como podemos fazer isso?

Exemplo:

```
var f = new FormData();
console.log(/** Qual é o nome da classe de 'f' **/)
```

Comment: A pergunta é específica para FormData ou mais geral?

Comment: É geral, @Sergio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a propriedade `name`, do constructor do objeto:

```
var f = new FormData();
console.log(f.constructor.name)
```

Comment: +1. Bacana. Essa aí eu não conhecia.

Answer (score 0):

Existe também essa pequena forma:

```
var f = new FormData;
Object.prototype.toString.call(f) // [object FormData]
```

Com a idéia do @felipsmartins, pode ser feito isso:

```
function get_class(obj)
{
    return obj.constructor.name;
}

get_class('uma String'); // "String"
get_class(1); // "Number"
```